# Помогите найти ошибку. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять, что сделал не так. Тесты, который были выложены в открытый доступ программа проходит, а где-то в тестирующей системе ломается.

### Условие

На вход подаётся строка. Необходимо посчитать для каждого входящего в неё символа длину наибольшей подстроки, состоящей только из символов, ему равных.

### Формат ввода

Одна строка с текстом. Длина строки не превосходит 100 символов. В строку входят только символы с ASCII-кодом от 32 до 126 включительно.

### Формат вывода

Нужно вывести
N строк, где N — количество различных символов в строке. В каждой из этих строк сначала должен идти символ, для которого она пишется, затем, через пробел, длина максимальной подстроки, состоящей только из такого символа. Строки вывода должны быть отсортированы лексикографически.

### Примеры:

### Пример 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Пример 2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Мой код

```
a = input()
col = 2
i = 0
my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    my_dict[a[i]] = 1
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] * col in a:
        my_dict[a[i]] += 1
        col += 1
    elif col > 2:
        i += col
    else:
        col = 2
        i += 1
for i in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: *где-то в тестирующей системе ломается.* Что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: У вас в дано: *Длина строки не превосходит 100 символов*. Вы ограничили обработку ввода? И это тоже: *В строку входят только символы с ASCII-кодом от 32 до 126 включительно.*?

Comment: @Tehnorobot этот текст наоборот говорит, что входные данные гарантированно удовлетворяют этим условиям, значит проверку на это добавлять не нужно.

Comment: @Tehnorobot, я имел ввиду, что при сдаче задания, тестирующая система говорит, что у меня ошибка. Обрабатывается только то, что ввели, смысла обрабатывать большее количество не вижу, если я вас правильно понял.

Comment: "Тесты, который были выложены в открытый доступ программа проходит" - это не так! Ни один из этих двух тестов программа не проходит! А поскольку код даже на приведенных двух примерах дает неправильные результаты, то ошибку  нужно искать самостоятельно. Примеры для того и даны, чтобы самостоятельно проверять работу кода

Comment: @Эникейщик жаль, а я уже хотел опубликовать правильное решение)..

Comment: @Эникейщик, да вы правы, прошу прощения, вынес константные значения в начало, и не подумал о том, что может что-то сломаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Что делает цикл `for`?

Он итерируется по объекту и присваивает значения элементов в переменную:

```py
for i in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5:
    print(i)
print(i)
```

Выведет:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
```

Вы, видимо, подумали, что значение `i = 0`, которые вы присвоили до цикла, останется и после него, но в вашем первом цикле вы изменяете значение `i` на индексы строки, потому после цикла значение `i == len(a) - 1`

Ок, исправляем, переносим `i` после цикла:

```py
a = input()
col = 2
my_dict = {}

for i in range(len(a)):
    my_dict[a[i]] = 1

i = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] * col in a:
        my_dict[a[i]] += 1
        col += 1
    elif col > 2:
        i += col
    else:
        col = 2
        i += 1

for i in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Проверяем приведённых значениях, вроде работает, а что если сделать не два, а три или более повторяющихся элементов .. не работает

## Проверка того, что впереди есть такая последовательность

В строке `a[i] * col in a` вы пытаетесь понять, существует ли последовательность символов такой длинны *впереди*, а проверяете, существует ли  такая последовательность во всей строке:
Есил ввести `"ataaa"`, то вот, что произойдёт:
(мы уже инициализиировали `dict` и в нём уже лежит `{"a": 1, "t": 1}`)

`if a[i] * col in a:`, проверяем

```
i == 0
a[i] == "a"
col == 2
a[i] * col == "aa"
```

следовательно `"aa" in a == True`, потому, что в `a` есть `"aa"`, хоть не в начале.

Ок, давайте исправим, используем срезы:

`if a[i: i+col] == a[i] * col:`

`a[i: i+col]` - это срез с индекса `i` до `i+col`, не включая, пример:

если `a == "abcdef", i == 3, col == 2`, то с той нашей строкой у нас будет `a[i: i+col] == "de"`

Ок, заменяем: `if a[i] * col in a:` на `if a[i: i+col] == a[i] * col:`
(Проверяем, что все буквы в срезе - те, что нам нужны)

Смотрим, что если ввести `"ataaapppp"`, опять не то считает ...

## Несколько длинных последовательностей

Логика таква, если есть последоательность такой длины, то мы задаём её, когда ма нашли конец последоательности, мы перезапускаем процесс, прасваивая `col = 2`, и перескакиваем к концу последовательности, , если же мы не находили последовательности, то просто идём дальше, и вот проблема, вы перескакиваете не к концу, а на один символ дальше, а также перепутали места, где мы перезапусчкаем процесс, исправляем:

```py
elif col > 2:
    i += col - 1
    col = 2
elif col == 2:
    i += 1
```

Такс, проверяем, вроде работает, а есди использовать `"ataaappppaaaaaaa"`, опять проблема, теперь с `"a"`

## Несколько одинаковых последовательностей

Каждый раз, когды вы находите более длинную последовательность, вы добавляете к максимуму, и если длинных последовательностей несколько, то вы будете добавлять и добавлять, исправляем:

```
my_dict[a[i]] += 1
```

на

```
if my_dict[a[i]] < col:
    my_dict[a[i]] = col
```

## Результат

В итоге у нас получается что-то такое:

```py
a = input()
col = 2
my_dict = {}

for i in range(len(a)):
    my_dict[a[i]] = 1

i = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i: i+col] == a[i] * col:
        if my_dict[a[i]] < col:
            my_dict[a[i]] = col
        col += 1
    elif col > 2:
        i += col - 1
        col = 2
    elif col == 2:
        i += 1

for i in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

## Альтернативы

Это далеко не лучший или не самый просто способ рещить эту задачу, вот идейка, как бы реализовать это лучше:

Идти по строке, и запоминать, какой был последний символ, и как долго он повторяется:

```py
string = input()
max_lengths = {}
sequence_length = 1
latest_symbol = None

for char in string:
    if latest_symbol != char:
        sequence_length = 1

    if max_lengths.get(char, 0) < sequence_length:
        max_lengths[char] = sequence_length

    sequence_length += 1
    latest_symbol = char

for i in sorted(max_lengths.items()):
    print(*i)
```

Comment: @Modnik если вам помог или понравится этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ловите алаверды. :) Для "оригинальнго исправленного" строка `"fooooooo baaar foo"` для `о` выдаст только 2, а должно быть 7.

Comment: Интересно, @GrAnd

Comment: @GrAnd, спасибо за замечание, и в правду, в моём решении я просто перезаписываю длину новой последовательности, вместо того, чтобы делать это только в случае если новая будет длиннее

Comment: @GrAnd, исправил)

Answer (score 1):

Если не брать в расчёт, что выбран довольно странный алгоритм для довольно простой задачи, то ошибка именно в вашем коде в том, что `i = 0` должно стоять не перед циклом `for`, а после него, непосредственно перед циклом `while`. Ибо цикл `for` испортил вам её и цикл `while` сработал всего раз только для последнего символа.

Вторая ошибка в том, что `col = 2` стоит в блоке `else`, где оно смысла не имеет, т.к. `col` там и так равен 2. А вот в блоке `elif` эта строка как раз необходима, иначе `col` застрянет на большом значении, и вы начнёте проскакивать другие последовательности.

Ну и третья ошибка - надо проверять только уникальные буквы. Или каждый раз сбрасывать счётчик. Иначе насуммируется лишнего.

В общем, если придерживаться вашей задумки, то код, по идее, можно представить как-то так:

```
a = "bee gees"
#a = "correct your mistakes"
#a = "fooooooo baaar foo"
col = 1
my_dict = {}
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] * col in a:
        my_dict[a[i]] = col
        col += 1
    else:
        i += 1
        col = 1
for i in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: Проверьте ваше решение для `"ataaappppaaaaaaa"`, пропускает `"t"`

Comment: @0dminnimda Ну я и сказал, что алгоритм изначально выбран "кривой". Оптимизации его подвергать совершенно бесполезно.

Comment: это да, еле-еле заставил работать в его "оригинальном" виде

Answer (score 1):

Другие участники уже указали на ошибки в коде и предложили рабочие решения. Я расскажу как решать задачу специфическими средствами Питона.

Прежде всего у нас есть строка (последовательность символов) и её надо разбивать на группы одинаковых символов. [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) решает эту задачу:

```
for k, g in itertools.groupby('abaa'):
    print(k, g)
```

> ```
> a <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f6b9ba171f0>
> b <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f6b9ba17e20>
> a <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f6b9ba171f0>
> ```

Со значением `g` надо поработать. Это объект, который итерируется по значениям группы. Нам значения не нужны, только их количество. В Питоне нет нужной функции, приготовим сами: `sum(1 for _ in g)`:

```
for k, g in itertools.groupby('abaa'):
    print(k, sum(1 for _ in g))
```

> ```
> a 1
> b 1
> a 2
> ```

Длины групп соберем в словарь, который для каждой встреченной буквы будет хранить максимальную длину. `d.get(k, 0)` возвращает `d[k]` если оно есть или ноль иначе. `sum` вы уже знаете. `d[k] = max...` обновляет максимум в словаре:

```
d[k] = max(d.get(k, 0), sum(1 for _ in g))
```

Когда словарь готов, его надо отсортировать (не сам словарь, а данные из него) и напечатать. `sorted` упорядочивает пары по ключу-букве. `f'{k} {v}'` печатает одну запись. `print(*..., sep='\n')` печатает записи в разных строках:

```
print(*(f'{k} {v}' for k, v in sorted(d.items())), sep='\n')
```

Соберем всё вместе:

```
import itertools


d = {}
for k, g in itertools.groupby(input()):
    d[k] = max(d.get(k, 0), sum(1 for _ in g))
print(*(f'{k} {v}' for k, v in sorted(d.items())), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ echo "correct your mistakes" | python longest_runs.py 
>   1
> a 1
> c 1
> e 1
> i 1
> k 1
> m 1
> o 1
> r 2
> s 1
> t 1
> u 1
> y 1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Ну и решение в одну строчку для гиков :)

```
import re

print(*map(" ".join, map(lambda x: map(str, x), dict(sorted((x[0][0], len(x[0])) for x in re.finditer(r"((.)(\2)*)", a))).items())), sep="\n")

#или
#print(*map(lambda x: " ".join(map(str, x)), dict(sorted((x[0][0], len(x[0])) for x in re.finditer(r"((.)(\2)*)", a))).items()), sep="\n")

#или
#print(*map(lambda x: f"{x[0]} {x[1]}", dict(sorted((x[0][0], len(x[0])) for x in re.finditer(r"((.)(\2)*)", a))).items()), sep="\n")

#или
#print(*map("{0[0]} {0[1]}".format, dict(sorted((x[0][0], len(x[0])) for x in re.finditer(r"((.)(\2)*)", a))).items()), sep="\n")
```

Comment: `dict(sorted` - хитро. :)

Comment: Ох ну зачем в одну строку-то ...

Comment: Чтобы уж по-настоящему в одну строчку, и импорт сожмите `re = __import__("re"); ...`

Comment: @0dminnimda Тогда уж `... __import__("re").finditer( ...`. Через `;` и простой `import` сработает.

Comment: @GrAnd, да согласен

Comment: @GrAnd Можно извернуться и сделать так: ```(lambda re=__import__("re"): ... )()```, чтобы каждый раз функцию не звать

Comment: Да, @GrAnd, значения по умолчанию в аргументах лямбды)

Answer (score 0):

Я предложу свой вариант кода(без `while`). Он, мне кажется, проще:

```
a = input()

my_dict = {}

for i in range(len(a)):
    my_dict[a[i]] = 1
count = 1
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    if a[i] == a[i + 1]:
        if my_dict[a[i]] <= count:
            my_dict[a[i]] += 1
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 1 
print(my_dict)

for i in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: Работает с `"ataaappppaaaaaaa"`, это хорошо, но, думаю, ваш метод сложнее чем тот, что предложил я в "альтернативах"

Comment: @0dminnimda Зато работает))

Comment: тоже верно, но я своё исправил, так что, уже не аргумент)

Comment: @0dminnimba Интересно, автор вопроса выберет хоть один ответ?..

Comment: @Modnik 2k17 если вас устроил чей-то ответ, то пожалуйста, выберите его как лучшее.

Comment: Ох, не знаю)) Ну, хоть upvote-ы получим), но тогда надо, чтобы у него было 15+ репутации, а у него 1 ...  (было)

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy предлагает изящные решения, я - подробный разбор ошибок + исправления и альтернативную реализацию, GrAnd - краткий разбор ошибок, с готовыми исправлениями (и почему-то еще не исправил ошибку, на которую я ему указал), вы предлагаете ещё вариант с исправленными ошибками. В зависимости от того, что автору важнее, я бы сказал, что он выберет меня или Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: @0dminnimda краткость - сестра таланта))) автор, я думаю, сможет разобрать небольшой код без пояснений 'средней сложности восприятия'. Ну, а так, то да, ваш ответ разобран подробно и ясно.